# what is the best way to deal with a lot of dataset of different type (case classes)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have like 50+ different case classes and each one is bound to a different parquet source

```
val cc1ds = spark.read("/hdfs/input1").as[cc1]
val cc2ds = spark.read("/hdfs/input1").as[cc2]
...
val cc50ds = spark.read("/hdfs/input1").as[cc50]
```

how to handle them in case of need to process them?
I cannot use

```
val res:(dataset[cc1], ... dataset[cc50]) = (cc1ds, ... cc50ds)
```

and I would like to avoid having so many vals defined

Comment: Are they all different schema ?

Comment: yes 50 + different parquet with different schema

Comment: usually when I have a few I use a `def` and return a tuple ex

```
val (ds1,ds2, ds3) = getDS
```